# How to open files from Juypter Notebooks?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, jupyter

Would like to create a notebook with links to files. I do not want to open the files in notebook. I am looking for functionality similar to Microsoft word's hyperlink where I can link to a file and the file opens in the appropriate app. I have been using

PDF

to open a pdf but it always tries to render

http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/New%20folder%20(3)/files/Module_1/Syllabus_FAY2020.pdf.

which is returns:

404 : Not Found
You are requesting a page that does not exist!

Is there any way to open files from Juypter Notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not the answer you are looking for but one can open files from within Jupyter like this:

```
!open my_file.txt
```